# newly studied javascript,here i have a problem while doing looping while

Tags: javascript

Why on the first case it stops at 11? Shouldn't it stop at 10?

```
var noAngkot = 0;
var Angkotoperate = 6;
var QuantityAngkot = 10
while (noAngkot <= QuantityAngkot) {
    noAngkot++
    if (noAngkot <= Angkotoperate) {
        console.log("Angkot " + noAngkot + " Beroperasi Dengan Baik");
    }

    else {
        console.log("Angkot " + noAngkot + " Tidak Beroperasi Dengan Baik")
    }
}
```

On the case below, when i use <, shouldn't it be 9? Why 10?

```
var noAngkot = 0;
var Angkotoperate = 6;
var QuantityAngkot = 10
while (noAngkot < QuantityAngkot) {
    noAngkot++
    if (noAngkot <= Angkotoperate) {
        console.log("Angkot " + noAngkot + " Beroperasi Dengan Baik");
    }

    else {
        console.log("Angkot " + noAngkot + " Tidak Beroperasi Dengan Baik")
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried following the logic of these two pieces of code on paper? Think carefully at what point exactly the `while` condition is evaluated and when you modify `noAngkot`

Comment: Don't forget to actually count zero

Comment: You have to think while place the loop increment variable in while loop.. that is  noAngkot++ .

Comment: solved,tq brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first example, you loop from 0 to 10 included (`0 <= noAngkot <= 10`) :

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 => that's 11 iterations
```

On your second example, you loop from 0 to 10 not included (`0 <= noAngkot < 10`) :

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 => that's 10 iterations
```

This is normal behavior.

The expected behavior you describe can happen if your start by defining `noAngkot` equal to 1:

```
var noAngkot = 1;
var QuantityAngkot = 10
while (noAngkot <= QuantityAngkot) {
    // this will output up to 10
    console.log(noAngkot)
    noAngkot++
}
```

---

```
var noAngkot = 1;
var QuantityAngkot = 10
while (noAngkot < QuantityAngkot) {
    // this will output up to 9
    console.log(noAngkot)
    noAngkot++
}
```